# google charts from google sheets query error

Tags: javascript

I am learning to use Goolge Charts.  I have no problem using the examples to make charts with hard coded data.  However, I would like to read in data from Google Sheets with a query.  I’ve spent days on this and followed all the examples I can find.  The bottom line is that I always get 'Error in query: Request timed out ‘.   I even get the error when I try to reproduce the google developers example.  There must be something (perhaps so simple) that I’m missing.  I’ve tried to strip down to the simplest possible code and speadsheet here.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1i6HW7VGwqJVsA1FwzgQuzRTRqPfBw_KQW4DNiqPct4M

I can also generate json file with longer URL
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1i6HW7VGwqJVsA1FwzgQuzRTRqPfBw_KQW4DNiqPct4M/gviz/tq?gid=209730183&headers=1&tq=

But I get a blank browser window with Error in query with html file below.

Really grateful for any help.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var opts = {sendMethod: 'auto'};

        var queryString = encodeURIComponent('SELECT A, B');

    
        var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1i6HW7VGwqJVsA1FwzgQuzRTRqPfBw_KQW4DNiqPct4M/gviz/tq?gid=209730183&headers=1&tq=' + queryString, opts);
      query.send(handleSampleDataQueryResponse);
    }

    function handleSampleDataQueryResponse(response) {
      if (response.isError()) {
        alert('Help! Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
        return;
      }

      var data = response.getDataTable();


        var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, { height: 400 });
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Janine, there is nothing wrong with your code. The chart displays properly - http://brisray.com/test/janine.htm

Are you trying to run this code locally? If so, then you are running into a CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) problem. This is common with the Google Charts API using Google Sheets. The HTML file needs to be uploaded to a web server, you cannot run it from your own PC, but oddly enough, because the Sheets have to be made public then I can use them from my own web pages.

Comment: Thanks very much for the response!  That's interesting information.  What I eventually learned from another comment I stumbled onto (a google chart forum I think) was that the current version of google charts had some new security hangups.  As advised, I used an older version with the call: google.charts.load('47', {'packages':['corechart']});

Comment: Rather than the default of current (which is version 49).  It worked immediately!  Thanks again.

Comment: Also, I should have said that yes, I was trying to run locally.

Comment: I was trying to run an import of my own google spreadsheet locally and it was failing. When I uploaded it to a website it ran correctly.  What made this particularly hard to diagnose is that the examples from the google charts documentation did run locally.